# Weak Convergence with Uniform Distribution $U[0; \theta]$ and Method of Moments

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, weak-convergence

We have  $(X_1, ... , X_n)$ an n-sample of a uniform distribution $U[0; \theta]$, where $\theta > 0$ and  moment estimate $\widehat{\theta}_n$ of $\theta$. 
\begin{eqnarray*}
                     \widehat{\theta}_n &=& 2 \overline{X}
\end{eqnarray*}

What can I say about weak convergence (in law) of $\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\theta}_n-\theta)$

> In the case of Maximum likelihood estimator gives $\tilde{\theta}_n$
>   if regular dominated model
>
> $$\sqrt{n}(\tilde{\theta}_n-\theta)\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{(l)}
> >  N(0,I_{\theta}^{-1})$$
>
> Thus
>
> $$\sqrt{n}I_{\theta}^{1/2}(\tilde{\theta}_n-\theta)\sim N(0,I_{\theta})$$
>
> and
>
> $$n(\tilde{\theta}_n-\theta)^T
> > I_{\tilde{\theta}}(\tilde{\theta}_n-\theta)\sim \chi^2(k)$$
>
> So we have an approximate $1-\alpha$ confidence region for
>
> $$\big\lbrace \theta: (\theta-\tilde{\theta}_n)^T
> > I_{\tilde{\theta}}(\theta-\tilde{\theta}_n) \leq
>  \frac{\chi^2_{k,\alpha}}{n} \big\rbrace$$

- So in summary my question is what is the analysis in the case of estimator of the method of moments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regardless of the distribution, as long as the 2nd moment is finite (which it is in this case), you know the weak convergence of $\bar{X}$ from Central Limit Theorem. Then use the fact that $\hat{\theta}$ is a linear transformation of $\bar{X}$.

Comment: By the central limit theorem,
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X} - \dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}\left(0, \dfrac{\theta^2}{12} \right)\text{.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the asymptotic normality holds only for regular cases, where one of the regularity conditions is that the support of the r.v $X$ is independent of the (unknown) parameter of interest. In the uniform case it isn't true and Fisher's information $I_{\theta}$ is basically irrelevant.

Recall that $\hat{\theta}_n = X_{(n)}$, thus 
$$
F_{X_{(n)}}(y) = P( X_{(n)} \le y) = (F_X(y) )^n = (y/\theta)^n, 
$$
thus
$$
P(n(\theta-X_{(n)})\le y)= 1 - P(X_{(n)} < \theta - y/n)=1-(1-y/(n\theta))^n,
$$
that is $n(\theta-X_{(n)})\xrightarrow{D} EXP(1)$. Where for any $0\le p<1$, $n^p (\theta - X_{(n)}) \xrightarrow{D} 0$.

For the method of moments estimator, just use the CLT, i.e., 
$$
\sqrt{n}(2\bar{X}_n - \theta) \xrightarrow{D} N(0, \theta^2/3).
$$

Comment: In order to clarify in your  answer you explain that the  procedure that I follow with Maximum likelihood estimator is wrong because X is not independent of he (unknown) parameter of interest. On other hand I'm more interested the case of method of moments estimator, can you go more deeper, what is the difference with the comment of @clarinetist.

Comment: No difference - If you divide the LHS by $2$ then you'll get his expression.

Comment: But you can say that $\frac{\partial F(y)}{\partial y}=f(y)=(\frac{n}{\theta})(\frac{y}{\theta})^{n-1}$ so you can get Fisher's information $I_{\theta}=-E_{\theta}[\frac{\partial^2 \ln f(y| \theta)}{\partial \theta^2 }]$

Comment: Yes, but it should equal $var(\partial / \partial \theta \ln f(\theta;x))$ that is $0$ in this case (because Uniform dist. is "irregular").

Comment: It means that $\sqrt{n}(\tilde{\theta}_n-\theta)\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{(l)} 0$. Can you suggest any reference to go more deeper?